# Different images show in same page when click on different link using javascript?

Tags: javascript

please improve this code. If we click on image 2 link . image link 2 no work.i also use more then 2 images in this code.

```js
<script>
        function changeImage() {
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            var img1 = document.getElementById('1');
            var img2 = document.getElementById('2');
            var img3 = document.getElementById('3');

            if (img1.id == 1 ) {
                image.src = "img/1.jpg";
            } 
            else if (img2.id == 2) {
                image.src = "img/2.jpg";
            }
            else if (img3.id == 3) {
                image.src = "img/3.jpg";
            }
             else
            {
                image.src = "img/5.jpg";
            }

        }
    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>JavaScript Can Change Images</h1>

    <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="img/0.jpg" width="180" height="180">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td > <a href="#" id="1" onclick="changeImage()"> Image1</a></td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="#" id="2"  onclick="changeImage()"> Image2</a></td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr>
            <td> <a href="#" id="3"  onclick="changeImage()"> Image3</a></td>
            
        </tr>
    </table>
   

    
please improve this code. If we click on image 2 link . image link 2 no work.i also use more then 2 images in this code. 
Thanks advance. 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Note that the names used for `id`'s need to begin with a letter, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>JavaScript Can Change Images</h1>

    <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="img/0.jpg" width="180" height="180">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td > <a href="#" id="1" onclick="changeImage(this.id)"> Image1</a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="#" id="2"  onclick="changeImage(this.id)"> Image2</a></td>

        </tr>
  <tr>
            <td> <a href="#" id="3"  onclick="changeImage(this.id)"> Image3</a></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
<script>
        function changeImage(click_id) {
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            var img1 = document.getElementById('1');
            var img2 = document.getElementById('2');
            var img3 = document.getElementById('3');

            if (click_id == 1 ) {
                image.src = "img/1.jpg";
            } 
            else if (click_id == 2) {
                image.src = "img/2.jpg";
            }
            else if (click_id == 3) {
                image.src = "img/3.jpg";
            }
             else
            {
                image.src = "img/5.jpg";
            }

        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: i also add another in img tag  for other images on same pages. What we do, and please also tell me, how can use multiple function for this purpose. Thanks Advance